# MYSQL / PHP Syntax Wrong - Using POST value

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following error about my syntax

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'replace='NOCOLOGY1' WHERE search='COMPANYNAME'' at line 1

```
$comp = "UPDATE msp_rereplacer SET replace='".addslashes($_POST[companyname])."' WHERE search='COMPANYNAME' ";
```

Can anyone pinpoint what I am missing?

Comment: `addslashes()` is not sufficient to prevent SQL Injection. Use a prepared/parameterised query.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: It is a one time use script, so security issues will not matter as I delete after one use!

Answer (score 2):

`replace` is   [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) try  **backticks**`replace`**backticks**

and

```
 .addslashes($_POST[companyname]).
```

should be

```
.addslashes($_POST['companyname']).

$comp = "UPDATE msp_rereplacer SET `replace`='".addslashes($_POST['companyname'])."' WHERE search='COMPANYNAME' ";
```

rather

```
$comp = "UPDATE msp_rereplacer SET `replace`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['companyname'])."' WHERE search='COMPANYNAME' ";
```

**Note**

Use of this extension`(mysql_*`) is discouraged. Instead, the [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

**Good Read**

[**`addslashes()` Versus `mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: Tried switching this, did not help

Comment: @JustinBevan try above query

Comment: WHy dont use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: It is working now using backticks, but this isn't for an actual program, merely a one time use script. Thanks though!

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary yup .... addslashes is more worse ,,,  rather i want to use  prepared statements

Comment: @NullPointer - I understand security risks by this, but this is for one time use (on multiple sites) - then deleted

Comment: @JustinBevan yup ... i agree ..i just think you like it to know

Answer (score 0):

replace is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).... quote it in backticks (`)

Comment: Tried $comp = "UPDATE msp_rereplacer SET 'replace'='".addslashes($_POST['companyname'])."' WHERE search='COMPANYNAME' ";  with no luck

Comment: backticks (`), not single quotes (')